# Will using pre trained word embeddings speed up model training in Pytorch? Also, what to do if some words of the dataset are not in the embeddings?

Tags: nlp, pytorch

I have a text classification model that passes word embeddings through a GRU and the output of that GRU is passed fed into an ANN that gives one class as an output.

The dataset is huge(1.4 million lines) and I am training it on Google Colab. It takes 15 mins to just go through 500 lines of the dataset.

So to speed up training, I decided to use pre-trained Glove vectors instead of the random embeddings that Pytorch provides. How do I implement that?

And any idea abou what should I do about missing words that are not in the Glove vectors? How will they be embedded?

Any other ideas about speeding it up will be appreciated.

EDIT:
Based on @scarecrow 's request for the code.
The code I used to convert embeddings to a float tensor:

```
print(f'First embedding: {embeddings[0]}')
print(f'The dimensions of the embeddings are: {len(embeddings[0])}')
embed = torch.FloatTensor([embeddings[0], embeddings[1]])
```

This is an example only. I thought it will be better to show what block of code is giving the error.

The error I get is:

```
First embedding: ['0.418', '0.24968', '-0.41242', '0.1217', '0.34527', '-0.044457', '-0.49688', '-0.17862', '-0.00066023', '-0.6566', '0.27843', '-0.14767', '-0.55677', '0.14658', '-0.0095095', '0.011658', '0.10204', '-0.12792', '-0.8443', '-0.12181', '-0.016801', '-0.33279', '-0.1552', '-0.23131', '-0.19181', '-1.8823', '-0.76746', '0.099051', '-0.42125', '-0.19526', '4.0071', '-0.18594', '-0.52287', '-0.31681', '0.00059213', '0.0074449', '0.17778', '-0.15897', '0.012041', '-0.054223', '-0.29871', '-0.15749', '-0.34758', '-0.045637', '-0.44251', '0.18785', '0.0027849', '-0.18411', '-0.11514', '-0.78581']
The dimensions of the embeddings are: 50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f8951bd3f739> in <module>()
      1 print(f'First embedding: {embeddings[0]}')
      2 print(f'The dimensions of the embeddings are: {len(embeddings[0])}')
----> 3 embed = torch.FloatTensor([embeddings[0], embeddings[1]])

ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a vocabulary of all the words that you need, such that each word gets a unique index in the vocabulary. Load the embeddings as a torch `Tensor` and load the embeddings as below: [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=embedding#torch.nn.Embedding)

```
>>> embedding_weights = torch.FloatTensor([[0.3, 0.6, 0.1], [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]])
>>> embedding = torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(embedding_weights)
>>> embedding(torch.tensor([1]))
tensor([[0.2000, 0.5000, 0.3000]])
>>>
```

Say, if a word "hello" corresponds to an index `2` in your vocabulary, `embedding_weights[2]` should contain the corresponding GloVe vector.

If you want to accomodate missing words in Glove, you can add those words to the vocabulary from the training set and add it to the `embedding_weights` tensor by assigning random tensors to them. The `Embedding` layer has to be trainable so that those randomly initialized tensors are learned by param updates during the training process.

EDIT: Added example

Comment: I have not implemented it yet. I will be doing it now. Just got a question. Since my embedding will be a mix of known word vectors and unknown randoms, won't this take the same amount of training time since pytorch will calculate grads for all the values. Or maybe I could use 2 different embeddings. One for known vectors which will have requires_grad = False and the second one for embeddings if the word is unknown and it will be trainiable?

Comment: I tried your solution. After fixing a lot of things and changing basically a major portion of my code, I created the embeddings list, and when I tried to create pre_trained embeddings in my GRU model by `embedding_weights = torch.tensor(embeddings, dtype=torch.float)`,  it gave me the following error: `ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'`

Comment: Did you try 'torch.FloatTensor' ? That is what is mentioned in the answer

Comment: Check the example added @PrashantGoyal

Comment: It is a 2-D list.

Comment: Solved the issue. It was due to each individual element of an embedding vector being a string. Thank you for your help.